# Kali Linux can't find any wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I have kali linux version 1.0.X(I suspect this to be 2/5) installed on my VM workstation 9. I haven't been using it for quite sometime.Now I got back to it but I'm running into the wireless card driver not detected-which I found it very common for such case (i.e backtrack/kali Linux on vms)- and I could get the driver and installed it but after that, when I do available wifi lookup I got no wifi-though my smartphone sitting next to my laptop is connected to the wifi I have at home-it just keeps on searching.

I did many searches and diggings here and there, but all failed:

I tried thses:

1. changing the [ifupdown] managed = from false into true in the network manager config. file but still no luck.
2. I tried to use an external wireless adapter (i.e TL- WN722N) but no luck as every time I try to connect it to the VM (bottom right of the vm-->click the USB icon-->click the connect (disconnect from host) but I got a message that this connection was unsuccessful due to the device being used. I Googled this too, and it turns out that VMs has no agreement with ports USB 3.0 and must only plug it to port 2.0. I tried that too, but NO LUCK too.
3. I also got my self the latest Kali-Linux version-so to be sure it's not the old version I have is corrupted. And I did the steps I mentioned but no luck too.

I feel I ran out of all solutions that I know, specially after I tried the external adapter.

Here I'm looking for any suggestions that could solve my problem.I need to learn the pen-testing, I just can't wait.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is well nigh impossible: the guest has no access to the host PCI bus, hence there is no way that the guest can control the host's wifi. That is so for all hypervisors, as of today, with a very small exception: under very restrictive circumstances, [VirtualBox can enable PCI-passthrough](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough), which allows transferring control of a PCI device (hence the wifi controller) from the host to the guest.

But the conditions are **really** restrictive: only Linux hosts, only ICH9 chipsets for the guest, presence of a IOMMU on the host motherboard,thence IOMMU support in the BIOS and the kernel, .... You can find them all described in the link above.

You true alternative, and the one we all used, is to buy a USB wifi adapter because that can be controlled by the guest.

Comment: I largely agree *on principle* but the specifics are incorrect. PCI passthrough is widely available, on every bare-metal hypervisor and most other Linux hypervisors as well. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pci+passthrough+kvm https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pci+passthrough+xen https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pci+passthrough+vmware - they do all require an IOMMU, but all full-fat x86 architectures have had the capability for 10 years+ (but it is often disabled for market segmentation purposes). USB is indeed much easier.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Thanks for letting me, I ignored this.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae if what I'm saying is impossible, so then what for the NATing & bridging options at the networks settings of the VM machine?Up to my humble knowledge is these two options provide the guest OS access to use the PC's wireless card to search and connect to available wifi or to share the same IP address of the host.                                         I did mention in number 2 what happen in the case where I used external wifi adapter.

Comment: @user1794499 They do not provide control of the network interfaces, they just allow the guest to communicate with the NICs, but the guest does not control the NICs at all.